# How to get the location of currently logined Dropbox folder

Tags: macos, shell, dropbox

I installed Dropbox.dmg
At first i logined with "xyz" credentials. I got Dropbox folder in /Users/Syammala/Dropbox. Then i logged out and logined with different credentials say "pqr".I then got prompt to select the location  for  Dropbox folder and then i gave /Users/Syammala/Desktop/Dropbox. And like that we get differenet locations for different user logins. All here i wanted to know is there any way to get path of Dropbox  folder for current user login. I am doing all this in Mac OSX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Dropbox desktop client writes information about the location of the local Dropbox folder to an "info.json" file that you can programmatically read.

For information on the location of the file and the format of the data in it, refer to this help article:

https://www.dropbox.com/help/4584

Comment: My Dropbox version is v3.6.8. In this i didn't find any info.json file. @Greg

Comment: Is the Dropbox client currently linked? Where did you look exactly? What operating system/version are you on?

Comment: Yes , I am currently linked.My os is OS X Yesomite Version:10.10.3. I searched for the file info.json using grep and also in  ~/.dropbox/info.json.

Comment: Ok, please feel free to open a ticket so we can help you troubleshoot this: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/contact