# How to get the Dropbox folder in Powershell in Windows

Tags: windows, powershell, dropbox

Same question exists for Python here: [How can I get the Dropbox folder location programmatically in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12118162/how-can-i-get-the-dropbox-folder-location-programmatically-in-python), or here for OSX: [How to get the location of currently logined Dropbox folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31380260/how-to-get-the-location-of-currently-logined-dropbox-folder)

Same thing in Powershell. I need the path of DropBox to copy files to it (building a software and then copying it to dropbox to share with team).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This Dropbox help page tells us where this info is stored, ie, in a json file in the AppData of the user: https://www.dropbox.com/help/4584

```
function GetDropBoxPathFromInfoJson
{
    $DropboxPath = Get-Content "$ENV:LOCALAPPDATA\Dropbox\info.json" -ErrorAction Stop | ConvertFrom-Json | % 'personal' | % 'path'
    return $DropboxPath
}
```

The line above is taken from: https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Spizzi.Profile/1.0.0/Content/Functions%5CProfile%5CInstall-ProfileEnvironment.ps1
Note that it doesn't check if you've got a Dropbox business account, or if you have both. It just uses the personal one.

You can then use this base Dropbox folder to build your final path, for example:

```
$targetPath = Join-Path -Path (GetDropBoxPathFromInfoJson) -ChildPath 'RootDropboxFolder\Subfolder1\Subfolder2'
if (-not (Test-Path -Path $targetPath)) { throw "Path '$targetPath' not found!" }
```

--

Alternative way is using the host.db file, as shown on this page:
http://bradinscoe.tumblr.com/post/75819881755/get-dropbox-path-in-powershell

```
$base64path = gc $env:appdata\Dropbox\host.db | select -index 1 # -index 1 is the 2nd line in the file
$dropboxPath = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String($base64path)) # convert from base64 to ascii
```